# popOver not following slider -iOS/ Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, slider, popover

I managed to insert a popover but i was not able to make the popover follow the UISlider.. it just displays on the lower right corner of the slider.. what am I doing wrong? How do I fix that? thank you in advance..

```
percentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 41, 33)];

UIImageView *percentImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 41, 33)];
[percentImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad-progress-value.png"]];
[percentView addSubview:percentImageView];

UILabel *percentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 41, 26)];
[percentLabel setTag:1];
[percentLabel setText:@"m"];
[percentLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[percentLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[percentLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];
[percentLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[percentLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
[percentView addSubview:percentLabel];

[_slider addSubview:percentView];
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the documentation suggests that the popover will follow the slider.  Putting the popover next to the control you specify is just a convenience since usually a popover will be launched by a user touching a button.

In general a popover doesnt "follow" anything or move.

If you know the position of the slider control you can use the following

```
- (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Providing the rect of the slider.

If you wanted to move the popover while its being displayed I think you will have problems with that, but you could look at UIView animation code and try to draw it yourself by subclassing UIPopover.